# Keychain returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

**Update at the end**

I'm using the pod 'KeychainSwift' and every time I try to get something from the Keychain it returns nil, this is my func to set the values:

```
    private func saveUser(email:String!, password:String!)->Bool{
        if keychain.set(email, forKey: "email", withAccess: .accessibleAfterFirstUnlock) {
            if keychain.set(password, forKey: "password") {
                print("User saved succesfully")
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }

    func setToken(token:String!){
        if keychain.set(token!, forKey: "token", withAccess: .accessibleAfterFirstUnlock) {
            print("Success...")
        } else {
            print("Error: Line 36 GeneraFire")
            print(keychain.lastResultCode)
        }
    }
```

and when I try to retrieve the value with this function:

```
func getToken()-> String!{
    return keychain.get("token")
}
```

it returns nil(the getEmail and getPassword also return nil).
I have turned on the Keychain Sharing capabilities and I have the entitlements. But it just wont work.

**Update**:
The actual problem just to be more clear is that I save the user through the saveUser function and it says it saved it successfully (error code 0) but when I retrieve it, it return nil with this error code "-25300" which I believe according to documentation it stands for "Item not found"

I made the modifications according to Yongjoon and it still won't work, (the link has the updated code now)

**Second Update**
I just put the same code GeneraFire in a blank project and it works fine. So some how my project is causing the problem.

Comment: As an aside, you wouldn't declare an argument to a function to be an implicitly unwrapped optional type.  Just use `String`; non optionality is then implied.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this issue caused by String! forcibly unwrap. All String in GeneraFire are declared by String!.

```
func getToken()-> String?{
        return keychain.get("token")
 }

 func getEmail()-> String?{
        return keychain.get("email")
 }

 if let status = result["status"] as? String! 
 >>  if let status = result["status"] as? String
```

> Use the conditional form of the type cast operator (as?) when you are not sure if the downcast will succeed. This form of the operator will always return an optional value, and the value will be nil if the downcast was not possible. This enables you to check for a successful downcast.

if let status = result["status"] as? String

1. result["status"] as? String

Since result["status"] returns an optional value, "as?" means  the value could be nil and casting as "String"

2. if let status

if casting result "result["status"] as? String"   has an optional value, unwrap and assign value to status.

Keychain Sharing capabilities has nothing to do with this issue. Since keychain is binding to the device not the App, if you need to share  keychain values between Apps in your device, then  you can  enable "Keychain Sharing capabilities"

Comment: thanks for the help and the tips, but sadly I just modified it and that wasn't the problem, every time I save the user it continues giving me nil

Comment: Any other idea?

Comment: 1.First,  make sure  all setter  and getter are working without using Alamofire. Just  hardcoding  the value,  to me its working.

Comment: Alredy done that, I changed the func to { let email = keychain. Get...  } and then I putted a break point just after and email is nil so the func work the problem is in keychain.get(“email”)

Comment: func login(email:String!, password:String!, completed: @escaping DownloadComplete){
        if(self.saveUser(email: email, password: password)) <--- this is entry point  to save right?.  can add  getter  right after this?..  and  I think  this always  saves email and password regardless of  login result(success, failure),  move to  success block?

Comment: mmm I could move it to the succes block and I think it's better there but I don't see how that resolves the original problem :/

Comment: if you don't mind,  you can create  a simple working version and send that to me. I can help you.

Comment: yes please, this is the link to github https://github.com/JCTec/GeneraIOS

Comment: As I am not able to access "Genera.dev", not test properly.

Comment: damn!!!!!!! I just find out what happend, It was such an stupid bug, before logging i was supposed to delete all previous data of the user, you know to prevent 2 user data to get mixed but apparently I was calling the function logOut just after loggingIn, Thank you so much for your help anyway